# Can I make a user specific method accessible in all twig templates?

Tags: symfony, twig

I am using Symfony2 with the FOSUserBundle. I have created a method where I ask if the user has done a specific action, e.g. `$user->hasVoted()`.

In my twig templates, I want to be able to ask

```
{% if user.hasVoted() %}
```

in **every** template (because it has an implication on which other partials to include), but I don't want to pass the whole `$user` object to each template.

Is there any way to make this user method accessible in all templates (or I could also pass the boolean value to all templates) without having to pass this explicitly to each template?

I know about [injecting variables into all templates from the Symfony cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html).

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        ga_tracking: UA-xxxxx-x
```

But the cookbook entry either tells how to inject static values (as in this example above), or how to inject services.

Is there an easy way how to include this one boolean value **without having to define a service** and inject it like this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        user_has_voted: "@acme_user.user_has_voted"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The authenticated user is available via `app.user` everywhere.

```
{% if app.user.hasVoted() %}
```

Or the cleaner way, you create a [twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html) like [`is_granted`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Extension/SecurityExtension.php). This enables you, to change the logic behind in future, without changing the templates.

Comment: Wow. As easy as that. And now where I see this answer, I remember that you can always access the current user like this. Thanks!

Comment: Warning, if you are not logged in, this call will fail, i suggest {% app.user ? app.user.hasVoted() : false %}

Comment: Yes. A reason why a custom twig extension is better. There you can prove this and other things :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, in your bundle boot() method:

```
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/AcmeDemoBundle.php
public function boot()
{
    $hasVoted = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->hasVoted();
    $this->container->get('twig')->addGlobal('user_has_voted', $hasVoted);
}
```

Comment: I like this answer (+1), but I prefer Pazis.

Comment: Didn't know about the boot method. @Paul when is it called?

Comment: It's called on the event kernel.request

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use the "attribute" twig function?

Something like that i guess :

```
{% if attribute(user, hasVoted) %}
```

Hope this helps!

(as [the doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/attribute.html) specifies it here)

Comment: But wouldn't this mean I would still have to pass the whole `$user` object to each twig?

Comment: Hmm you're right, I thought it was already the case but Pazi's suggestion is far better! (and doesn't force you to pass the whole user to all your twigs!)